# How do I stop orca from starting up on login?

Tags: startup-applications, orca

Orca keeps starting up after system starting, and I'm not able to find it in "Startup Applications".

How to stop it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run this in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/orca-autostart.desktop
```

change `NoDisplay=true` to

```
NoDisplay=false
```

Save, then open up *Startup Applications* and disable the entry for *Orca*.

Comment: what is the diff between gksudo and sudo

Comment: a couple of links, you can google others, http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#head-a76e0b38808fca380fa209babb080d60ffe0ec8e

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 13.10, open "Universal Access" and turn off screen reader

The "Seeing" tab is the default and includes this option

[image: Couldn't use image, so here's a link]

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to disable Orca. It will stop and won't bother you at next logon.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `orca-autostart.desktop` from `/etc/xdg/autostart`. Run:

```
sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/orca-autostart
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)