# How can I disable the "voice" feature (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: keyboard

Ok.. now I feel really stoopid. I researched this as best I can, but haven't been able to locate anything about this particular occurrence.
I must have inadvertently clicked a key or combination of keys that result in the computer "voicing" any keys that I type. This is not 'reading the content on the screen' kind of thing - just voices the keys as I input them. I'm sure this is a software or something that is resident on the computer through Ubuntu as an aid to the visually impaired (for instance)... and you can load it as needed. This situation happens particularly upon sign-in and seems to go away after logging in - and is not a factor when using the keyboard for Internet browsing or anything - but it's back again after I sign off and re-boot the computer (again - at the sign-in prompt). It's great to have my password requested and have it "announced" as I type it - to whomever might be within earshot. No, really...
Anyway, how can we disable this (under different circumstances, I'm sure) useful/helpful feature?
We are running Ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok... me again. I did some additional detective work (trial and error, really) - and this is it:
You can access the "Screen Reader" feature on the sign-in screen (within the options of the drop-down menu, located in the upper right-hand corner of the screen), and select it (via Ctl+S) or deselect it, as the case may be. 
That's all. I don't hear voices any more. :p
Thanks everyone, anyway.
:)

Comment: This was a freaky occurrence as I somehow accidentally turned this on. I found [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278693/how-do-i-stop-orca-screen-reader) helpful