# How do I get Ubuntu voices to turn off

Tags: menu

Somehow suddenly Ubuntu is reading menu's to me - with a computer voice. How do I turn that off?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just have to find the right setting.

1. Open "System Settings..." (for example by clicking on the gear in the top right)
2. Choose "Universal Access"
3. Open the "Seeing" tab if not already in focus
4. Toggle the switch next to "Screen Reader"

You can also toggle Screen Reader using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

If neither of those work try killing it and uninstalling as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/278697/205638).