# Voice coming out of computer when browsing

Tags: accessibility

My husband is running Ubuntu 14.04.  Recently, every time he moves the mouse, a voice is telling him what button / link / drop down box he is touching.  It may be an application to enable blind users to move around the screen, but he doesn't need it and can't find how to get rid of it.  Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop Orca Screen Reader?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278693/how-do-i-stop-orca-screen-reader)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like somebody has accidentally turned on Orca, a "screen reader" to help people with impaired vision.

Few people actually need it so I'd suggest [removing it completely](https://askubuntu.com/a/278697/449). Open a terminal and fire in:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-orca
killall orca
```

Or you can simply toggle it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>