# keyboard shortcut to turn off screen reader and zoom

Tags: shortcut-keys

My cat has gotten into the habit of sitting on the keyboard of my laptop running Ubuntu. Somehow he must have stepped on a combination of keys that causes screen reader and zoom to activate after the computer is powered on but before the Ubuntu GUI launches. I turned off the screen reader within the Ubuntu, so everything is normal after the GUI launches, but every time I boot the computer, it comes up with screen reader and zoom activated. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what key combination my cat might have used to set the screen reader and zoom to activate during launch, because I doubt if my cat remembers what he did.

Comment: Without further details it's difficult to determine but could it be `Orca`. If so [this reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278693/how-do-i-stop-orca-screen-reader) might help.

Comment: try by going into Settings --> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Universal Access -> Disable Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: I tried the following command: sudo apt-get remove orca    That one worked. Then I tried
sudo apt-get remove gnome-orca and
killall orca. Neither of those last two worked. When I rebooted, the screenreader was silenced but the screen is still zoomed in when I boot.  How can I get rid of the screen zoom that is activated at startup and just have a normal display at boot? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Gnome running Ubuntu 22.04 - it may work for you as well.

Undo magnifier:  Super+Alt+8
Undo screenreader: Super+Alt+S