# How to turn off narrator of Ubuntu?

Tags: accessibility

Recently I downloaded ebook speaker applications from Ubuntu Software Center. After that I'm facing this problem. Whatever I type, it keeps on narrating. I don't which application I've opened. No application seems to be open. I've to mute the speaker. Any solution ?

Comment: Can you at least tell us the name of the application?

Comment: @Braiam It's "Ebook Speaker". After restarting my pc, problem was solved. But, if same case is repeated, I want to know solution without restarting system.

Answer (score 23):

System Settings -> Universal Access -> Seeing -> Screen reader -> Off

Or a hotkey "Alt-Super-S"

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. "Orca Screen Reader" was installed in my laptop, which I realized and uninstalled it. And then the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need that software too can't do that. Got any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to stop screen reader

[stop orca from starting up on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81960/how-do-i-stop-orca-from-starting-up-on-login)

For Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 14.04, open "Universal Access" and turn off screen reader

The "Seeing" tab is the default and includes this option

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem in the Elementary os.the solution I found that:-

1. Open System Setting
2. Now go to the sound setting and select Application Tab.
3. there are many speech-dispatcher options. mute and check them one at a time.